# Gap between video that shouldn't be there (unwanted scrollbar)

Tags: html, css, video, padding

I'm trying to have the whole screen filled up with a mp4 video, but for some reason theres a scroll bar at the bottom and a bit of whitespace on the side

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" preload="metadata">
            <source src="space.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support this video</video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
}
```

[screenshot of bar at the bottom that isn't wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2fap.jpg)

Comment: Did you try *{margin:0; padding:0;}? Or use 100vh and 100vw, which are viewports for full width and height, as well as box-sizing: border-box; and maybe overflow:hidden

Comment: margin and padding worked, thanks :)

Comment: Then I will add it as answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Every blank page has some padding or margins I ain't sure wasn't looking into that so you can use:

bad solution:

```
* {   margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

or better solution

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

Using * means all so it will apply to all elements and it is slow. But for me sometimes html, body does not work.

Also you can try using `100vw and 100vh and box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a link to your site? Also did you try adding the `!important` tag to the overflow property.